# inspecting u. v = u.w

Tags: linear-algebra

If the components of **u**, **v** and **w** isn't given is there anything we can learn about the relationship between **u** and **v** (not **w**) from the equation **u**.**v** = **u**.**w**?

Comment: You know that v-w is orthogonal to $u$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know *nothing* about any of the three vectors, then no. You do not know anything about $v$, and its relation to $u$, because for example, you could have $w=v$ in which case the equation would be trivially true.

All you really know is that, since $u(v-w)=0$, is that $v-w$ must be orthogonal to $u$.

---

If you know that $\pi_v(w)=\pi_u(w)$ ($\pi_v$ is the projection onto the subspace generated by $v$), then you do know a couple of things:

- If $w=0$, then the projection inequality tells you nothing, but in that case you know that $v-w=v$ is orthogonal to $u$, so you know $u,v$ are orthogonal.
- If $w\neq 0$, then you know that $v$ and $u$ are colinear (because $\pi_v(w)=\lambda v$ for some $\lambda$ and $\pi_u(w)=\mu u$ for some $u$).

Comment: Thank you, 5xum. If I add that Proju(w) = Projv(w), does u.v = u.w start to get meaning then? I think not. Proju(w) = Projv(w) simply means that u and v lies on the same line and are scalar multiples of one another. u.v = u.w still doesn't shed on light the relationship between u and v. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Tightrope I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks again. There are some symbols that you've used that I am not familiar with but let me try to rephrase what I think it means.If w = 0 then the  orthogonal projections (terms used in the textbook I use) can't say much but then we do now that u and v are orthogonal from u.v = u.w because u(v - w) = 0. If w doesn't equal 0 then they are colinear or the phrase that I used in my previous post "on the same line and scalar multiples of one another." Is this right?

Comment: @Tightrope The only symbol I introduced is $\pi_u$ which is what you called "Proju".

Answer (score 2):

Since scalar product is distributive, we get
$$
\mathbf{u\cdot v = u\cdot w}\\
\mathbf{u\cdot v-u\cdot w = 0}\\
\mathbf{u\cdot(v-w) = 0}
$$
which means that $\mathbf{v-w}$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf u$. We can't get any more information, because the first equation is fulfilled by any two $\mathbf v, \mathbf w$ such that $\mathbf{v-w}$ is orthogonal to $\mathbf u$.

Geometrically this means that the normal line / plane (depending on dimension) of $\mathbf u$ that contains $\mathbf v$ also contains $\mathbf w$.